# In react-native, after calling using linking.openURL(tel), not navigating to my app

Tags: react-native, openurl, tel

I am using

```
onPress={() => Linking.openURL(`tel:+91 {Mobile}`)}
```

It's calling to **`{Mobile}`**
But after call it's not navigating again to my app automatically

how to navigate to my app automatically